# Unset a tomcat response header

Tags: tomcat

How can I unset a header on apache tomcat ? I have a third party app on my tomcat server that respond some request using "X-Frame-Options: deny" can i somehow unset that header?.

notice that using HttpHeaderSecurityFilter I was able to overlay the header, using ALLOW-FROM, but that dont work on chrome.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
      <param-value>ALLOW-FROM</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>antiClickJackingUri</param-name>
      <param-value>http://myothersite/</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `antiClickJackingEnabled` is `false`, Tomcat does not add the header  "X-Frame-Options: deny" to responses.

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

If it does not work only on Chrome, you may have to remove cache on Chrome.

Comment: You are right. tomcat doe not add the header X-Frame-Options:deny, but the response already come from the app with that header. what i need is some way to remove, unset that header.

In [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) say that chrome is not compatible with the ALLOW-FROM feature.